# BlobMessages in ActiveMQ "Classic"?

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

In the last versions ActiveMQ "Classic" does not offer anymore the utility to store files transferred with blob messages. Does ActiveMQ Artemis have it? Which solution have you found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In May of 2015 the fileserver was disabled by default via [AMQ-5754](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5754). This change first appeared in versions 5.11.2 and 5.12. Then in May of 2016 (i.e. one year later) the fileserver was removed completely via [AMQ-6276](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6276) under the assumption that anybody actually using blob messages would use a proper FTP or file server for their needs. This change first appeared in version 5.14.

That said, blob messages were a kind of partial solution to the problem of moving large chunks of data via JMS since the blog message is just a kind of "pointer" and actually moving the data requires some out-of-band transport mechanism (e.g. HTTP, FTP, SCP).

ActiveMQ Artemis has support for arbitrarily [large messages](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html) which allows you to send potentially huge chunks of data to the broker using just the JMS API (i.e. no out-of-band transport mechanism required).

Comment: At one point the file server was removed from the broker as it was insecure.  Maybe that's what the question references although it is to vague to know for sure.

Comment: Yes, I was speaking about this change... Ok. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer to address this.